# Vertical spacing for dynkin-diagram labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, phantom

I'm trying to achieve the same vertical alignment for labels with different heights inside dynkin diagrams provided by the `dynkin-diagrams` package.

`\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d}]{F}{4}` gives

[image: picture]

My attempt to fix this has been to use `\vphantom`like this

`\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={\vphantom{b}a,b,c,d}]{F}{4}`

but it fails. Any help?

Comment: This problem is fixed in the latest version of the dynkin-diagrams package, out today on CTAN, using one of the solutions given below by Schroedinger's Cat.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay : I am using the newest version of `dynkin-diagrams` and everything works fine (thank you!), but the new default vertical spacing for labels breaks the spacing between lines of text (e.g., when using `$\dynkin[Coxeter]{F}{4}$` inline). Is there a way to set the vertical spacing back to zero through the `label depth` and `label height` params? (forgive my inability with tikz).

Comment: Good point. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Would you have a quick (no matter how dirty) solution? I'm using your package in my thesis and I was planning to have it printed in a couple of days.

Comment: The quick solution: \tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/text style/.append style={text height=0}}
\tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/text style/.append style={text depth=0}}

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay : I opened a new question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518992/vertical-spacing-for-edge-labels-in-dynkin-diagrams with already two partial solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all the macros get expanded in the internal routines of the package. The package has a key `label macro` for wrapping macros around the labels. However, as the `dynkin-diagrams` is Ti*k*Z based, there is a very simple fix using the `every label` key:

```
/tikz/every label/.append style={text height={height("b"}}
```

I survey several options in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Original diagram}
\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d}]{F}{4}

\subsection*{Using \texttt{every label}}

\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d},
/tikz/every label/.append style={text height={height("b"}}]{F}{4}

\subsection*{Defining styles}

\pgfkeys{/Dynkin diagram/.cd,
dlabel height/.style={/tikz/every label/.append style={text
height={height("#1"}}},dlabel height/.default=b,
dlabel depth/.style={/tikz/every label/.append style={text
depth={depth("#1"}}},dlabel depth/.default=g}

\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d},
dlabel height]{F}{4}

\subsection*{Using \texttt{label macro}}

\dynkin[Coxeter,labels={a,...,d},label macro/.code={\vphantom{b}#1}]{F}{4}

\newcounter{icheat}

\noindent
\dynkin[Coxeter,labels={1,...,4},label macro/.code={\vphantom{b}\setcounter{icheat}{#1}\alph{icheat}}]{F}{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added an analogous style for the depth because if you have, say, a `g` in the labels the analogous problems will arise.

**ADDENDUM**: The `dynkin-diagram` package starting from version November 27 2019 has styles that take care of that. Now you only need to play with `label height` (and `label depth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Original diagram}
\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d}]{F}{4}

\subsection*{Using styles}

\dynkin[Coxeter, labels={a,b,c,d},label height=d]{F}{4}

\subsection*{Using \texttt{label macro}}

\dynkin[Coxeter,labels={a,...,d},label macro/.code={\vphantom{b}#1}]{F}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you! Could you just explain the last case where you use `icheat`? I don't understand what the code should do nor I see any difference in the output.

Comment: @Sirion The last example is not particularly relevant. It just shows how one can convert a number into a letter.