# Vertical spacing for edge labels in Dynkin diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

This question follows the update to the package `dynkin-diagrams` made available by the author after [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517692/vertical-spacing-for-dynkin-diagram-labels).

I am using the newest version of `dynkin-diagrams` and everything works fine, but the new default vertical spacing for edge labels breaks the spacing between lines of text.
E.g., when using `$\dynkin[Coxeter]{F}{4}$` inline there is too much space between the current line of text and the previous, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to set the vertical spacing "back to zero" for edge labels? (forgive my inability with tikz).

**UPDATE - MWE**

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[10]
    $\dynkin[Coxeter]{F}{4}$
    \lipsum[10]
    \end{document}
```

**UPDATE (3/12/2019): PARTIAL SOLUTION**

- The author (@BenjaminMcKay) of the package in a comment to the [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517692/vertical-spacing-for-dynkin-diagram-labels?noredirect=1#comment1312617_517692) suggests to use this code

```
    \tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/text style/.append style={text height=0}}
    \tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/text style/.append style={text depth=0}}
```

to restore the previous behaviour, however in my attempts this breaks correct spacing for vertex labels if set globally.

- The user @Schrödinger'scat suggests below to use the following code

```
    \tikzset{dlabel sep/.style={every label/.append style={inner sep=#1}}} 
    $\dynkin[Coxeter,label height=4,label depth=.,dlabel sep=0.5pt]{F}{4}$
```

which does what I need and doesn't break alignment of vertex labels.
However, to be absolutely sure that the dynkin diagrams doesn't mess with vertical spacing between lines I added a `\smash` (just to stay safe) and removed the `label height=4` param which is not relevant in this case.

```
    \tikzset{dlabel sep/.style={every label/.append style={inner sep=#1}}} 
    $\smash{\dynkin[Coxeter,label depth=.,dlabel sep=1pt]{F}{4}}$
```

Comment: I added a MWE. As for your curiosity, see the comment to my previous question by the author of the package himself.

Comment: If you want a quick and dirty solution, use `$\dynkin[Coxeter,label height=a,label depth=4]{F}{4}$`. Turns out the styles made it to the package. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, it's much better indeed, but the gap between the two lines is still slightly bigger than the default one... as I am going to use it in my phd thesis (that I should print very soon) I'd really appreciate a complete solution (no matter how dirty the code is). For example, is there any way to set the depth and height of the character "_"?

Comment: Found it! `label height=.,label depth=.` will do (but the edge label will be a bit too close to previous line...).

Comment: Yes. What you probably want is to set the `inner sep` and `outer sep` of that label to 0. I do not know the package in that much detail, but I am afraid you need to "hack" it again for the time being if you want to achieve this urgently, or make a feature request.

Comment: You can achieve any spacing with `\raisebox`: `$\dynkin[Coxeter,label height=\raisebox{2pt}{.},label depth=.]{F}{4}$`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure to understand your last comment: with your code I can increase the distance between the two lines as much as I want, but actually to improve this `$\dynkin[Coxeter,label height=.,label depth=.]{F}{4}$` the only thing left to do is to make the label `4` a bit closer to its edge, which is not what `\raisebox` seems to do.

Comment: `\tikzset{dlabel sep/.style={every label/.append style={inner sep=#1}}}
$\dynkin[Coxeter,label height=4,label depth=.,dlabel sep=0.5pt]{F}{4}$`.

Comment: Excellent!!! I don't have to restore any parameters after using `\tikzset`, right? (Tomorrow I'll check that this patch doesn't break something somewhere else). Thank you A LOT!

Comment: You would only break something if someone else has defined a style of the same name, and you had overwritten it. To be on the safe side you could rename `dlabel sep` to `Sirions strange dlabel sep`. You will only affect those diagrams in which you use that style. (In principle one can check if a style of that name exists already.)

Comment: I am working on an update to take care of this. I hope to post an update to CTAN in a day or two.

Comment: Nice! If I may I would suggest to keep edge labels closer to the graph than vertex labels, so that they can be easily distinguished even when one has both vertex labels and edge labels on the same side of the graph (i.e., both above or both below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The problem seems to be solved with the latest version of [dynkin-diagrams](https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams), just loaded to CTAN about 10 minutes ago.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[10]
$\dynkin[Coxeter]{F}{4}$
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```